# Regex to match key value pairs from JSON

Tags: java, json, regex

I need to match all the key values pairs from a complex JSON, but only values that are text / String.

For example from:

```
{"results":[
{"id":16,"name":"some name1","location":"some  location1","parent":true, ,"region":"some region"},
{"id":157,"name":"some name2" , "location":some location2","parent":true}
],"totalCount":170}
```

I need to match:

```
"name" 
"some name1"
"location"
"some location1"
"region"
"some region1"
etc
```

I have this `[^:]+\"(?=[,}\s]|$)` , but it only matches the values (which are correct).

I need also to match the keys: "name" , "location", "region" (and there can be other key names)

Here is an example for values matched https://regex101.com/r/m8FePZ/6

Comment: Do you _have_ to use RegEx? In 99.9% of cases you should not use RegEx to parse something in a standardized machine-readable format, like JSON (or HTML, XML, etc). You should use your programming language's native JSON parser. What language/environment are you working in?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why not just parse and loop through keys? Micro-optimization? Or dealing with insanely huge dataset?

Comment: Don't try to parse JSON with a regex.  You will regret it later.  There are so many edge cases and things that can go wrong that you haven't thought of.  Use a proper JSON parser in whatever language you're using.

Comment: If you're doing something from the shell, then look at a tool like `jq`.  Here's [an article](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/7-things-never-code/) I wrote that includes a brief example of how `jq` can be used.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I use JAVA, but I could do it in any language. The data is not critical if something goes wrong with the regex (only testing purposes). I want to do a small script that parses any multi level json objects and obfuscate the values by adding instead the key and a random number. It is not known what the JSON will contain. I looked into different libraries, but none of those helped me to achieve this and parsing it with Jackson, for example, and converting it to a Map implied going down in all the levels inside the JSON which can be a bit complex.

Comment: Update: Did the processing myself with a JSON library and then parsing object (list, map or key values pairs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, if you want a robust solution use a JSON parser in your language.

If you want to use regex, and the engine supports lookbehind you can use this:

```
/("[^"]*"(?=:")|(?<=":)"[^"]*")/g
```

Explanation:

- `|` - or combination of:

  - `"[^"]*"(?=:")` - quote, 0+ non-quotes, quote, followed by positive lookahead for colon and quote
  - `(?<=":)"[^"]*"` - positive lookbehind for quote and colon, followed by quote, 0+ non-quotes, quote

If you want to exclude the quotes in the matches, use this regex:

```
/(?<=")([^"]*(?=":")|(?<=":")[^"]*)/g
```

Note that these regexes fail for cover corner cases, such as whitespace around keys and values, escaped quotes in values, etc. Hence it is safer to use an actual JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you decided not to use regex and used JSON library finally. Here is the simple solution by "Josson & Jossons".

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.22'

---------------------------------------------

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\n" +
    "    \"results\": [\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"id\": 16,\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"some name1\",\n" +
    "            \"location\": \"some location1\",\n" +
    "            \"parent\": true,\n" +
    "            \"region\": \"some region\"\n" +
    "        },\n" +
    "        {\n" +
    "            \"id\": 157,\n" +
    "            \"name\": \"some name2\",\n" +
    "            \"location\": \"some location2\",\n" +
    "            \"parent\": true\n" +
    "        }\n" +
    "    ],\n" +
    "    \"totalCount\": 170\n" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
        "results.entries().[value.isText()]*.toArray()");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
[ "name", "some name1", "location", "some location1", "region", "some region", "name", "some name2", "location", "some location2" ]
```